# Newly created issues (JIRA and python)

Tags: python, jira

I am working on simple app that uses python to access Jira. 
I mange to get all the issues How to get the only newly created issues ?

```
from jira import JIRA

jira = JIRA(basic_auth=('username', 'password'), options={'server':'https://MY_JIRA.atlassian.net'})

got = 50
total = 0
while got==50:
    issues = jira.search_issues('project=JA', startAt = total)
    ....
    got = len(issues)
    total += got
```

Comment: @MarcusMüller dude - we were all inexperienced once, this is a really unhelpfully condescending comment. It's clearly obvious to you, but perhaps it's not obvious to OP

Comment: @jolyonruss thank you so much for your comment :)

Comment: @jolyonruss no insult intended; I meant to say, "hey, you already know how to look for issues, so look for issues that match your criteria" (and that does, indeed, feel a bit obvious). OP certainly knows better how the states of his projects are configured than I do (believe me, companies have the weirdest state flow for their own Jira setups), and researching ways and outlining how OP would approach that would make this a question that would actually be attracting detailed, meaningful answers!

Comment: @MarcusMüller intended or not, your comment doesn't meet SO's be nice criteria https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice which is surprising given you've clearly contributed a lot here. Maybe try not to make so many assumptions about what OP may or may not know. Maybe they don't already know how to search for issues? Maybe they don't know the state of their JIRA projects? Maybe they're frustrated to be working on a Sunday and just need a little bit of help?

Comment: Again, my intention was to be nice. I'm sorry it didn't come across that way. I, however, really don't see much reason to discuss further – I don't think PythonP went out here with a mental scar, and I'm really trying really hard to not be offended by the fact that both of you consistently accuse me of acting condescendently, albeit having tried to push OP into the right direction :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting newly created issues will involve you creating a new JQL query - here's a [get started with JQL page](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/jira-software/jql-the-most-flexible-way-to-search-jira-14) from the Atlassian blog.

From the examples at the bottom it looks like you can query by relative date like this:

`assignee is EMPTY and created < -1d`

I hope that helps.